# Logo not showing

Tags: html, css, blogger

I am using Google Blogger. I just changed template of my blog and choose a new one. But there is a problem with this one. My logo is not fully showing.

My website: [www.pkgeek.com](http://www.pkgeek.com)

The K of the logo is missing. I tried to find the code for the logo, but didn't find. I think the author haven't typed specific code for the logo.

I think the blogger it self is doing some customization.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: wa alykom elsalam, remove header width

Comment: @Abudayah Yea, i just do that ^_^ Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Your div is way too small for you Logo :).

Just go in your css file and paste this code.

```
'#header { width: 30%; }'
```

I put 30% in case you need to add some things on the right of your logo, if not, just put 100% it goes well.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Thank you :D Instead of putting % i put 267px xD

Comment: You can =D but be aware that using px is not really recommended for <div> placement. % has advantage to adjust the width according the user's screen. Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

`#header` needs to be set to `width: 267px` instead of `220px` in your css